# Unterschied zwischen senden / zusenden / versenden / absenden / übersenden

Tags: prefix

Worin besteht der Unterschied zwischen diesen Verben? Besonders versenden und senden sind mir unerklärlich...

Comment: Was sagt denn das Wörterbuch und welche Fragen bleiben danach noch offen?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Diese verschiedenen Varianten von "senden" drücken in der Regel einen unterschiedlichen Fokus des Sprechers aus. Außerdem dienen längere, umständlichere Wörter oft der Höflichkeit.

Die einfachste Form ist das *Senden* an sich. Das kann man im Grunde stets einsetzen. (In allen Beispielen weiter unten kann man statt *xxxsenden* auch einfach *senden* sagen, ohne dass Wesentliches jenseits von Stil und Höflichkeit verloren ginge.)

Beim *Absenden* liegt der Fokus auf dem Umstand, dass das Paket, der Brief oder was auch immer, nun endlich auf der Post ist. Der Vorgang des Absendens ist hier der Wichtige. Was dann weiter geschieht, wie lange das Paket unterwegs ist, ob es je zugestellt wird und so weiter, ist dem Sprecher in diesem Moment nicht so wichtig.

Beim *Zusenden* geht es umgekehrt besonders um den Moment, in dem das Paket (der Brief, die Sendung) beim Empfänger ankommt. Sowie um den Umstand *dass* die Sendung beim Empfänger ankommt.

Beim *Versenden* ist es ähnlich wie beim *Absenden*, jedoch hat man eher eine massenhafte Verarbeitung von Post vor Augen (nicht einen, sondern hundert Briefe).

Beim *Übersenden* fällt das Augenmerk auf den Umstand, dass der versandte Gegenstand vom Zugriff des Absenders auf den Zugriff des Empfängers übergeht. *Übersenden* wird in der Regel in höflichen Ausdrucksformen verwendet.

Hier einge typische, wohlgeformte Sätze mit diesen Wörtern:

> Sekretärin zum Chef: "Ich bin noch nicht dazu gekommen, den Brief **abzusenden**. Ich mache das gleich morgen früh."
>
> Privatperson an Firma: "Könnten Sie mir bitte den neuesten Modelleisenbahnkatalog **zusenden**?"
>
> Oder ein kleines bisschen weniger höflich: "Könnten Sie mir bitte den neuesten Modelleisenbahnkatalog **senden**?"
>
> Teamrunde in der Werbeabteilung der Firma: "Wir sollten endlich unsere neuen Kataloge **versenden**. Die Kunden warten schon, und die Paletten aus der Druckerei stehen schon seit letzter Woche bereit."
>
> Anschreiben der Firma an die Kunden: "In der Anlage **übersenden** wir Ihnen den neuesten Modelleisenbahnkatalog."

Comment: Danke für die Antwort. Und wie wäre es mit heraussenden (raussenden)? Wann benutzt man das Wort?