# Difference between “schicken”, “abschicken” and “zuschicken”; similar verbs?

Tags: verb-usage, prefix, separable-verb

Like many students of German, I guess, I'm having trouble distinguishing verbs with different prefixes. My teacher says “schicken”, “abschicken” and “zuschicken” are close synonyms with subtle differences but doesn't go farther than that. I have already read (what I could of) [this related question](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/38620/unterschied-zwischen-senden-zusenden-versenden-absenden-%C3%BCbersenden) but I would like to get some examples of actual usage, i.e. what goes mostly with each verb, and also what absolutely doesn't go.

Also, are the connotations of *ab-* and *zu-* when used with *schicken* or *senden* found in other verbs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [already found question](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/38620/unterschied-zwischen-senden-zusenden-versenden-absenden-%C3%BCbersenden) has in my opinion an sufficient answer regarding [ ]  / ab / zu.
Because `senden` and `schicken` is close enough in your cases to be used interchangeably.

some examples

- Ich schicke Dir ein Paket.
- Ich schicke das Paket ab.
- Ich schicke Dir das Paket zu.

*A verb with different usage of zu & ab:*

- schließen
- decken

Because `zuschließen` is quite clear to close the lock (of a door/ etc.). But `abschließen` can be used both ways when it comes to mobile locks. And `abdecken` is in my experience double used as well (while `zudecken` has unique meaning).

- Ich schließe das Fahrrad ab

  - = es ist nun fest angeschlossen*
  - AS WELL AS das Schloss ist ab und das Fahrrad ist fertig zum wegfahren
- Ich decke den Erdhaufen ab

  - = Ich habe eine Plane über den Erdhaufen gelegt.
  - AS WELL AS Ich habe die Plane vom Erdhaufen entfernt.

Which implies: a door cannot be open after `ich habe die Tür abgeschlossen`

*user unknown hints that `abschließen > anschließen`, because `abschließen` is more general locking while `anschließen` implies sth. where the locked object gets attached to (just the usage takes not always care of that subtle difference).

Comment: Thanks a lot. Just to clarify: is *abschicken* not allowed to take a dative object? I'm reading that happens with *verschicken*.

Comment: @pablodf76 Yes, that's correct. You can't say "Ich schicke es dir ab"