# Was ist der Unterschied zwischen "verschicken" und "abschicken"?

Tags: prefix, separable-verb

In welchem Kontext gibt es dieser Unterschied? Danke!

Comment: Willkommen bei German.SE. Für eine gute Frage gehört auch das eigene Verständnis der beiden Begriffe hinzuzufügen (sogenannte eigene Recherche). Und auch: in welchen Textbeispielen entsteht das Verständnisproblem. Was bleibt bei der ähnlichen Frage wie https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/50737/difference-between-schicken-abschicken-and-zuschicken-similar-verbs unklar?

Answer (score 4):

Der Unterschied ist minimal. "Abschicken" ist ein etwas kurzfristigerer Prozess. Wenn ich eine Email schreibe, dann ist "abschicken" nur der Prozess des Knopfdrückens auf den "Senden"-Knopf. Zum "Verschicken" gehört aber auch schon der Prozess des Email-Schreibens.

"Kannst du bitte ein Paket an Oma verschicken", bedeutet, dass das Paket noch nicht gepackt ist. Du sollst es einpacken, beschriften und zur Post bringen.

"Kannst du bitte das Paket für Oma abschicken", bedeutet, dass das Paket schon verpackt und beschriftet ist. Du sollst es nur noch zur Post bringen.

Comment: Vielen Dank für die Antwort! Dadurch, dass ich nicht Deutscherin bin, hatte ich Schwierigkeiten, diesen Unterschied zu verstehen. Nun ist es klar.